# Delete query based on results from other query mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to run a delete query in mongodb that will use another query results:

For example I have documents with the following data:

```
    [{
     'hash': '12312521',
     'done: false,
     'type': 'bla'
    },
    {
     'hash': '12312521',
     'done: true,
     'type': 'bla'
    },
    ]
```

Steps:

1. Run a query that will return all the hashes with done = false.
2. Take the hashes from step 1 and delete them where done = true.

Only the first doc will be deleted

Please help

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Because the result of query 1 yields documents with `done === false` so nothing will be deleted in the second query.

Comment: @DimiVi there are documents with the same data except the 'done'
I want to delete all the duplicated documents that have the same hash but delete only those with the done: true